# Как поставить сегодняшнюю дату в API

Tags: php, дата

Пробую поставить дату вот так `' <?php $today = date('Y-m-d');?>'`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://site.ru/v3/prices_for_dates?origin=MOW&destination=AER&token=**********&depart_date=' <?php $today = date('Y-m-d');?>'");
```

Не получается.
Мне нужно к `depart_date=` добавить сегодняшнюю дату, как ее поставить правильно? Спасибо

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Обычной конкатенацией

```php
curl_setopt(
  $ch,
  CURLOPT_URL,
  "https://site.ru/v3/prices_for_dates?origin=MOW&destination=AER&token=**********&depart_date=" . date('Y-m-d')
);
```

Comment: не получилось. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Arcadiy не верю. Ваш код содержал синтаксическую ошибку. Я ее исправил. Тогда приведите в вопросе текст ошибки

Comment: Вы ковычкой двойной обрубили

Comment: @Arcadiy что я обрубил? Соберите третий параметр в отдельную переменную и посмотрите ее значение

Comment: **&depart_date=" Здесь ковычка не нужна

Comment: @Arcadiy Вы не поверите, но именно там она и нужна

Comment: Если это открывающая, то где закрывающая ковычка?

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!